# Shrinking variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I'm building a JavaScript compressor and I'm at the "shrinking local variables" stage.  I've been comparing the results of my compressor with various online compressors and noticed something interesting with [Dean Edwards' /packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/).

Let's take this snippet of the jQuery library as an example:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
  var document = window.document,
      navigator = window.navigator,
      location = window.location;
});
```

My compressor returns the following code:

```
(function(a,b){var c=a.document,d=a.navigator,e=a.location});
```

but /packer/ returns this:

```
(function(a,b){var c=a.document,navigator=a.navigator,location=a.location});
```

Is there any reason why /packer/ does not shrink variables after the first in a var list?  Is it simply a bug or is there a reason?

At first glance it would appear that my compressor is doing the right thing and will give a better final result, however let's look at another example from the jQuery library:

```
var jQuery = (function() {

  var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
      return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    },
    // some other vars
    rootjQuery;
    // etc...
});
```

This snippet is important because the variable `rootjQuery` is referred to before it is defined.

In this case /packer/ does the same thing and only compresses the first var in the list:

```
var jQuery=(function(){var c=function(a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b,rootjQuery)},rootjQuery});
```

However my compressor messes up the code a bit because although it does not compress `rootjQuery` when it is mentioned in the return statement (because it has not been defined yet), it does compress it when it is defined later.

```
var jQuery=(function(){var a=function(b,c){return new a.fn.init(b,c,rootjQuery)},b});
```

This obviously causes an error when trying to execute the code.

Is there any way round this?  It looks like Dean Edwards noticed this problem so got around it by only compressing the first var in a list so that on the odd occasion that a case like this pops up, it won't cause an error.

I have tried singling out variables that are used before they are defined and not compressing them, but it's not that simple because in this case `rootjQuery` is used at a different scope than it is defined at.  I have no way of knowing which scope it will be defined at until I get to it.

Comment: Not sure. Creating three `var` statements (instead of using the comma) *does* smallen all three, although there should not be any difference in side effects.

Comment: Sounds like you can't compress as-you-read, but need to build up a complete appreciation of the source file (and any globals coming from external to the source) before you can attempt to compress. I can't see a reason why you couldn't compress the 2nd, 3rd, etc variables in a `var v1, v2, v3, ...` list though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment about the rootjQuery param being required, save me some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my compressor now.

As Paul Grime said in the comments, it was necessary to build up a whole list of all the variables and their scopes before compressing anything.

JavaScript allows things to be referenced before they are defined, so there is no way around this.